# How to create a locale in java with a certain currency

Tags: java, localization

I have a java application in which the user is allowed to set the locale. One of the locales is Arabic (Lebanon). This locale works perfectly except that I would like the $ sign to be the currency symbol and not the lebanese currency. How can I create a locale which is just like the Arabic (Lebanon) locale except that it has a different currency? thanks.

EDIT:
I have a locale choose which is filled as follows:

```
locales = Calendar.getAvailableLocales();
localeCount = locales.length;
for (int i = 0; i < localeCount; i++) {
      addItem(locales[i].getDisplayName()); 
}
```

I would like to create one custom locale which acts exactly like the Arabic (Lebanon) locale when it comes to formatting dates, numbers and language with the sole difference of having the US currency ($) instead of the Lebanese L.L. (ل.ل in arabic).

Comment: Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: Also paste actual and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: This is how you can print currency code see here for different country map [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/i18n/locales-list.shtml)

```
java.util.Locale locale=new java.util.Locale("ar","LB");
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale); 
System.out.println("Arabic(LB): " + currency.getSymbol(locale));
```

In my case it is not showing symbol

```
Arabic(LB): ?.?.?
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a way to replace the currency of the locale and not print it out.

Comment: Yes, for this you have to initialize locale with Arabic (Lebanon) it auto load currency, timezone, date format etc

Answer (score 0):

like this maybe:

Locale aLocale = new Locale("ar", "LB");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).